# Can we setup client and server side rendering on same react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, tizen

I would like to create a react app which should have both server and client side rendering so that we can take build accordingly using different npm commands

I've tried configuring but got issue as i had two package.json

Comment: React server components are not still out, they will be shipped soon with React 18. You can use a fw like NextJS to make partial SSR.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be flexible with your rendering strategies, you can use Next.js as it let you choose how to render your page according to your needs :

Server-side rendering, Client-side rendering, and static-site generation.
If you want to learn more about next.js rendering you can refer to the [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/pre-rendering)

Comment: this is not an issue with rendering I am facing issue with backend interaction

Comment: I am expecting my solution to be with nodejs so that i can add other micro services as well also having requirements on nodejs